# How to connect two stages of circles using CSS

Tags: html, css

Folks,

We are trying to connect two lines with different stages but it seems stage2 is moving to different line.

How to connect these two stages(circles) with lines so that they appear on same line. As of now always it is coming to new line.

Code below :

```css
.circle {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.circle-inner {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<font face="Times New Roman" size="1">stage1</font>
<span class="circle" style="display:block">
 <span class="circle-inner" style="display:block"></span>
</span>
<hr style="height:1px; margin-top:-10px; border:none; color:#000; background-color:#000;width:80px;margin-left:22px">
<font face="Times New Roman" size="1">stage2</font>
</span>
<span class="circle" style="display:block">
 <span class="circle-inner" style="display:block"></span>
</span>
<hr style="height:1px; margin-top:-11px; border:none; color:#000; background-color:#000;width:80px;margin-left:22px">
```

Comment: I suggest you make a Stack Snippet out of your code so we can run it right here in your question.

Comment: change `display:block` to `display:inline-block` in you inline-styles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```css
.circle {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.circle-inner {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:inline-block;">
  <font face="Times New Roman" size="1">stage1</font>
  <span class="circle" style="display:block">
 <span class="circle-inner" style="display:block"></span>
  </span>
  <hr style="height:1px; margin-top:-10px; border:none; color:#000; background-color:#000;width:80px;margin-left:22px">
</div><!--
--><div style="display:inline-block;">
  <font face="Times New Roman" size="1">stage2</font>
  <span class="circle" style="display:block">
 <span class="circle-inner" style="display:block"></span>
  </span>
  <hr style="height:1px; margin-top:-11px; border:none; color:#000; background-color:#000;width:80px;margin-left:22px">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You say there in your inline-style:

```
<span class="circle" style="display:block">
<span class="circle-inner" style="display:block"></span>
```

Block elements cause adjacent elements to be placed on a new line. Instead, try using `display:inline-block`:

```
<span class="circle" style="display:inline-block">
<span class="circle-inner" style="display:inline-block"></span>
```

By the way, there is no reason to use an inline-style at all, you can add this definition to your style in the head.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```css
.circle {
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
padding:5px;
background: white;
border: 1px solid green;

}
.circle-inner {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  background: green;

}
.line_up {
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="line_up">
  <font face="Times New Roman" size="1">stage1</font>
  <span class="circle" style="display:block">
    <span class="circle-inner" style="display:block"></span>
  </span>
  <hr style="height:1px; margin-top:-10px; border:none; color:#000; background-color:#000;width:80px;margin-left:22px">
</div>
<div class="line_up">
  <font face="Times New Roman" size="1">stage2</font>
  <span class="circle" style="display:block">
    <span class="circle-inner" style="display:block"></span>
  </span>
  <hr style="height:1px; margin-top:-10px; border:none; color:#000; background-color:#000;width:80px;margin-left:22px">
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a small explanation with your code. So that some one can understand what you have tried by without digging the code.